# Two domain controllers took forever to boot

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-name-system, active-directory

Recently we had a power outage that was greater than 2 hours. We had to shutdown 8 out of 9 servers. I left 1 server, server6, running because it hosts web services we need 24/7. Once the power was back on, I tried to boot server1 and server2 first, considering server1 is the main operations master and server2 is our DNS server. Both of the systems were stuck at "Loading Network Connections" for about 10-20 minutes. Once the systems were booted, I logged in and the Event Viewer was filled with errors.

Server1 had:

```
The Security System detected an authentication error for the server LDAP/SERVER1.  The failure code from authentication protocol Kerberos was "There are currently no logon servers available to service the logon request.
```

(0xc000005e)".

and

`Dynamic registration or deletion of one or more DNS records associated with DNS domain 'DomainDnsZones.JVS.' failed.  These records are used by other computers to locate this server as a domain controller (if the specified domain is an Active Directory domain) or as an LDAP server (if the specified domain is an application partition).`

Server2 had:

```
Dynamic registration or deletion of one or more DNS records associated with DNS domain 'JVS.' failed.  These records are used by other computers to locate this server as a domain controller (if the specified domain is an Active Directory domain) or as an LDAP server (if the specified domain is an application partition).
```

and

```
The Security System detected an authentication error for the server ldap/server2.JVS.  The failure code from authentication protocol Kerberos was "There are currently no logon servers available to service the logon request.
```

(0xc000005e)".

I went into Active Directory Sites and Services and tried to connect to the JVS forest numerous times with failed attempts. Finally after about the 8th try, it found the forest and everything went back to normal. This gives me the feeling something is wrong with our domain. Is there any tests I can run to see what is wrong with our domain? Has anyone ever heard of this happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every AD server should have DNS on it too. You probably ended up with a AD server that couldn't connect to the DNS server because the DNS server couldn't find the AD server to authenticate against.

Comment: So every Domain Controller needs DNS server installed on it?

Comment: No, all domain controllers need to have a DNS to talk to AT ALL TIMES. This basically means that your last server should have DNS running. 2 DNS per AD is a minimum.

Comment: @Jacob Not necessarily, but if a domain controller can't contact DNS during boot, it'll take forever to get back up and running as you've just dealt with.  Sounds like you've only got one DNS server, you definitely want more than that.

Comment: Thank you for the help. server1 and server2 are our DNS servers. server2 is primary and server1 is the alternate. On server1 should the primary DNS server be server2 and alternate be server1?

Comment: It looks like I need to make sure server1's DNS server is working correctly.

Comment: @Jacob, what do you mean by primary and alternate? MS-DNS AD-Integrated Zones have no master/slave relationship like traditional DNS.

Comment: @Jacob: You've created a dependency that creates this scenario when both your AD and your DNS servers are down and powered back up at the same time. You can alleviate this by installing the DNS role on your AD server and/or installing the AD role on your DNS server. You can ignore the events in the event log as they're a result of this specific scenario and once the two servers are finally able to communicate with each other the events should cease to be logged. What you're seeing is exactly what I'd expect to see with your configuration.

Comment: If both server do in fact have DNS installed then each server should have itself listed as the first (primary) DNS server in the TCP/IP properties of the NIC.

Comment: @joeqwerty - I actually saw the opposite recommended directly from Microsoft. Each AD server should reference another server for DNS, and reference itself as secondary.

Comment: @SpacemanSpiff: If I'm not mistaken that was only applicable for W2K before MS resolved the "DNS island" problem. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/275278

Comment: @SpacemanSpiff, I've seen that recommended in places too, but I always go with the config Joe pointed out. I've never had problems, but haven't seen any issues with the config you suggested either. YMMV.

Comment: Good information, I'll adjust moving forward!

Comment: @Joeqwerty & Chris S - MS Best Practice Analyzer for 2008 R2 DCs will inform you that your DCs should point to an different DNS server for primary and localhost for secondary.  (I don't think it would be helpful when all DNS servers are down though...)

Comment: @Clint: That's news to me. Thanks for the heads up.